# image thumbnail, with max-width, and max-height -- onmouseover, view a bigger image somehow

Tags: javascript, html

I've set a thumbnail to have a max-width and max-height and need to set up some kind of onmouseover setup to where when they hover over the image, it shows them a bigger image.

I cannot use links to do this.

Any ideas?

html

```
<img src="imageurl" class="s3_right" style="max-width: 400px;">
```

I tried using the code below; however, it messes up because I have a max-width/max-height.

html

```
<img src="image url" class="s3_right" onmouseover='Big(this);' onmouseout='Small(this);' style="max-width: 400px;">
```

javascript

```
<script language=javascript>
<!--
function Big(me)
{
me.width *= 2;
me.height *= 2;
}
function Small(me)
{
me.width /= 2;
me.height /= 2;
}
-->
</script>
```

There is also the problem that maybe x2 will be larger than the actual image.  I don't need the code to expand the image larger than the actual image is.  So I would really just need the code to set a new max-width and max-height or popup the image off the page with a max-width and max-height (like, not actually change the layout because the image thumbnails are displaying with text wrapped around them.)

Comment: I found that http://scripterlative.com/files/magnifimage is a great code and does exactly what I want, except it requires the use of a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a possibility to just spoof an absolute positioned duplicate, along with the thumbnail, nested inside a wrapping div assigned a relative position?

```
<style type="text/css">
    .meDiv
    {
        position:relative;
        border:1px solid black;
        width:200px;
        height:100px;
    }

    .meSmall
    {
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }

    .meBig
    {
        z-index:10;
        position:absolute;
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
        display:none;
        width:800px;
        height:350px;
    }
</style>

<div class="meDiv">
    <img class="meSmall" src="imageURL" onmouseover="Big();" />
    <img id="bigOne" class="meBig" src="imageURL" onclick="Small();" onmouseout="Small();" />
</div>


<script language="javascript">
function Big() {
    document.getElementById('bigOne').style.display = "block";
}

function Small() {
    document.getElementById('bigOne').style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Obviously the code given won't directly plug into your scenario or win any awards, but it's just to give an idea of the concept.

Using this you could apply whatever size restrictions you want to the wrapping div and/or thumbnail (bugs with max-width/max-height permitting) without affecting the large image or dislodging any wrapped text. You could also use the characteristics of the thumbnail to determine traits of the large image if you need to by employing a bit of JavaScript black voodoo magic (I'm a jQuery fan myself).

Comment: No problemo. Looking at the 'magnifimage' you mentioned in your comment to the question; I believe it does the same as this anyway but just positions the absolute div relative to the mouse cursor location (swapping sides if you go more than half way across the screen).

Comment: Yeah, I contacted the owner of the script and found out more information about it as well.  From what I found in the info it was telling to attach it to an <a> tag; however, found out once i already had the other solution that it could be attached to an img as well.