# jQuery inserting and removing images from divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, lightbox

Is there a way with jQuery to insert an image into a div on click, and remove it on click?

I am trying to make a light box with jquery, so on dom ready, it applies the thumbnail class to each image in the wrapper div, and then on click it toggles the full class. But that creates centering problems. So I'd like to have a transparent div that goes to .5 opacity and inserts the clicked image, then when you click again, does the opposite.

here's the code I have so far:

```
        $(document).ready
            $('img, div.wrapper').each( function() {
                var $img = $(this);
                $img.addClass('thumbnail');
                $img.click(function(){
                    $img.toggleClass('full');
                });
        });
```

link to the js fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/reveries/TLJYN/

I just want to add a div that will be width and height 100% and 50% opaque which will have text-align set to center. This way when the image is injected into this div, it will automatically center. Then when clicked, the 50% opaque parent div will display:none and the image will be put back where it was before.

Comment: Any chance you could drop some of your HTML markup along with the CSS and this JS into http://jsfiddle.net/. It would help to get a look at what you are running up against.

Comment: [The answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603936/image-thumbnail-with-max-width-and-max-height-onmouseover-view-a-bigger-im/15604931#15604931) might help, depending on what you are after exactly.

Comment: yeah, sorry. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/reveries/TLJYN/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will clone the clicked image into the div. You can change the css and the rest to your needs

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img, div.wrapper').each( function() {
        var $img = $(this);
        $img.addClass('thumbnail');
        $img.click(function() {
            $img.clone().appendTo('#big');
        $('#big').fadeToggle('slow');
    });

    $('#big').click(function(){
        $('#big').fadeOut('slow').html('');
    });
```

});

I also changed some CSS. See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/TLJYN/6/).

Comment: so that last line $(this).html(''); does it remove the cloned img from #big?